# Text Area new Line - Spring mvc vs Liferay Spring MVC portlet

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay, textarea

In my Liferay Spring MVC portlet new lines on Text Area do not work, while in a plain Spring MVC context they are working.

*Plain Spring MVC*

Text area tag is `<form:textarea path="theTextArea"/>`

User input contains three separate lines:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

On submit when I inspect the bean at server side it contains `aaa\r\nbbb\r\nccc` and the same is saved in the database.

On my view page I am using `<pre><c:out value="${theBean.theTextArea}"></c:out></pre>` and I see three lines on page.

But the same is not working in the Liferay Spring MVC portlet.
New line are converted to *blank space*:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

is converted to `aaa bbb ccc`.

I don't know how to solve this problem in Liferay.

The liferay spring mvc jsp code

```
<form:textarea
    path="titleofEvent"
    id="titleofEvent"
    name="titleofEvent"
    class="input-large" rows="" cols="" maxlength="600" tabindex="1"/>
```

Comment: You give details on your working code, but not on your code that fails. How do you expect us to tell you what you'll have to change when all we know is that a "Liferay Spring MVC portlet" is involved?

Comment: Hi Olaf I am using same spring tag with some bootstrap css <form:textarea path="theTextArea" class="input-large"/>

Answer (score 0):

Liferay uses the `StripFilter` to compact white spaces in the response. Usually it tries to keep the content of `<input>` and `<pre>`. Unfortunately instead of looking for `<textarea>` it is looking for `"textarea "` (with a space at the end).

So if you add *any* attribute to your textarea, the content should keep all newlines in the tag.

Comment: Thanks Tobias for the answer, can you let me know, what do you mean of  "you add any attribute to your textarea," if possible share the code.

Comment: If you add your the interesting part of your portlet to your question, I can add the modification to my answer. Btw. which Liferay version are you using?

Comment: Hi Tobias, I am using liferay 6.2 (liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp6).And I have updated my question to add the jsp code of liferay Spring mvc.It is same with Only Spring MVC code

Comment: Thinking about it: are the new lines not correct in the submitted value, in the database, or in the output (in the `pre`)?

Comment: it not correct on submitted value(so on db also).In liferay new line converted  blank space (aaa bbb ccc) where standalone spring mvc converted  to  \r (aaa\r\nbbb\r\nccc).

Comment: I will have to modify or delete my answer then, because what I was talking about was a problem in the output...